# IOs App freezes at splash screen only when updated

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, app-store-connect

We have just released an updated version of our app on itunes. Everything works fine when users who currently do not have the app on their device download it. However it freezes at the splash screen if users try to do an update.

I am guessing this might be some cache related issue since the newer version is indeed totally different and also smaller in size. Could this really be the case or might it be due to something else?

We would really like to avoid publishing a new build to itunes but having current users not being able to update the app is also not very efficient.

Comment: 100% related to the code executed on load... so show some code ;)

Comment: It could be many reasons, check data structure compatibility between old and new version, especially which are stored in NSUserDefaults, Keychain etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happens for different reasons, but I propose some ideas:

- the settings are stored differently and this might freeze the app
- some other changes in cached data : different file format, etc...

One way to solve it is to trace this using the debugger, or put some logs in and use the Device tool to look at the log and track and identify the issue